# jQuery AJAX sending link show broken

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
var dlink="http://www.example.com/downloadPkpass.php?temp=f5d022b2-8596-45e7-811d-611d42a15b6c&serial=100000000000135";
jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:'../sendMail.php',
                data: "date="+date+"&vname="+vname+"&offer="+offer+"&expiry="+expiry+"&dlink="+dlink,
                success:function(res)
                {

                },
            })
```

I used this snippet for my jQuery Ajax code.the problem is with the dlink variable. 
But in the sendMail.php page where I print the $_POST
,it is showing in a broken array not showing the original data.
in sendMail.php it is showing like this:

> [dlink] =>
>   http://www.example.com/downloadPkpass.php?temp=f5d022b2-8596-45e7-811d-611d42a15b6c
>   [serial] => 100000000000135

Comment: your `dlink` has an `&` in it and hence it is splitting into two `post`ed variables in PHP

Comment: how to solve it?I have to send this to 2 values.temp and serial in a single link.

Comment: You're going to have to replace any `&`'s with something unique and then reverse replace that unique value with an `&` on the `dlink` value in PHP,

Comment: @RobSchmuecker No, you just need to encode the value correctly.

Comment: @jeroen yes you are correct, that's the best solution.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Of course technically you are correct, the unique thing being the encoded character ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your values correctly for use in a url. The easiest way is to have jQuery do that automatically by passing an object:

```
data: {'date': date, 'vname': vname, 'offer': offer, 'expiry': expiry, 'dlink': dlink},
```

You can also encode the value manually if you should want to (when you don't use jQuery for example):

```
var dlink=encodeURIComponent("http://www.example.com/downloadPkpass.php?temp=f5d022b2-8596-45e7-811d-611d42a15b6c&serial=100000000000135");
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong method to declare data

```
 data: "date="+date+"&vname="+vname+"&offer="+offer+"&expiry="+expiry+"&dlink="+dlink,
```

data is in the format of below:-

```
data: {date: date, vname: vname,offer: offer, expiry: expiry, dlink: dlink},
```

Comment: No, it's not wrong, you just need to encode the values correctly. jQuery actually transforms the object to an encoded query string as that is the format required to send in a javascript ajax request.

Comment: @jeroen thanks for your guidance. I read this  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and correct my answer.